# Why does it take long to load an ionic project in cloud9?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cloud9-ide

I am working in a cloud IDE (cloud9) and have followed the instructions on their website to start an Ionic app (https://docs.c9.io/frameworks_ionic.html):

```
 $ npm install -g cordova ionic
 $ ionic start myApp tabs
 $ cd myApp
 $ ionic serve $PORT
```

Doing so, when I go to my page that the server points to, it takes up to one minute to load the page. Is this normal because I am in a cloud environment or is there something fishy? When I do simple projects with AngularJS it loads it immediately...

Comment: I created a new ionic project in Cloud9 just then and it only took a second to start up. Perhaps it was a temporary performance problem with your machine? Is it still going slow?

Comment: Really weird, yes it is still going slow somehow. When I press Live Preview then it does work quickly (immediate). Only when I use ionic serve then it takes this long to load the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic team member here. So this is most likely because you are using a cloud based IDE.

Starting a sample app locally and running `ionic serve` produces no where close to a one minute load time. This probably because Cloud9 wasn't build to handle a live reload from their servers, to a users machine.

Comment: Oke thank you. Good to know. When pressing Live Preview on Cloud9 it actually loads much quicker (immediately), so it could be also something with that?

Comment: Well their live preview is probably optimized for their set up. Our live reload server is optimized for local development.

Comment: Nevertheless, Ionic is the bomb!

Answer (score 6):

start your app in the C9 terminal with "ionic serve $PORT --nolivereload" and your pages will load at light speed. C9 doesn't support ionic live reload.

Comment: This should be the excepted answer because it gives a specific C9 solution which is what the question called for.

Comment: This is beyond helpful! Got a course in Ionic and you gave me great insight into what to do first!!